# Verificar si una persona de la tabla, tiene una columna igual a 1 PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

intente hacer una verificación, que si por ejemplo, un usuario de la base de datos tiene la columna llamada "verificado" es igual a 1, por lo tanto, tendría que darle el color al verificado, mientras que las otras personas que tienen el valor 0, no tengan ningún color. Este es el código que intenté utilizar.

```
$conn = new mysqli($database,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$id=$_GET['uid'];
$nombrefile = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `verificado` FROM `mybb_users` WHERE uid='$id'");
if ($nombrefile == 1) {
echo "<img src='{$useravatar["image"]}' style='border: 8px solid #0d34ff;' alt='' width='85' height='85' />";
}else
{
echo "<img src='{$useravatar["image"]}' alt='' width='85' height='85' />";
}
?>
```

Pero tengo un problema, el color les dá a todas las personas, tengan el valor 0 o 1, ¿que devo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El cambio lo debes hacer aquí:

```
$nombrefile = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `verificado` FROM `mybb_users` WHERE uid='$id'");
if ($nombrefile == 1) {
```

Y lo colocas de esta forma:

```
$conn = new mysqli($database,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$id=$_GET['uid'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `verificado` FROM `mybb_users` WHERE uid='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if ($row['verificado'] == 1) {
echo "<img src='{$useravatar["image"]}' style='border: 8px solid #0d34ff;' alt='' width='85' height='85' />";
}else{
echo "<img src='{$useravatar["image"]}' alt='' width='85' height='85' />";
}
```

Con esto te vas a traer en $row el valor de "verificado" en la base de datos.